# Need help to find the filename

Tags: java, exe, runtime.exec

I used the following code to run an exe I load through my code.

```
private static String filelocation = "";
```

.

```
  load_exe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
           JFileChooser file_Choose = new JFileChooser();

           file_Choose.showOpenDialog(frame);
           JavaSamp.filelocation = file_Choose.getCurrentDirectory()
                    .toString()
                    + "\\" + file_Choose.getSelectedFile().getName();
           System.out.println("FileLocation" + JavaSamp.filelocation);
        } catch (Exception expobj) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        try {
           System.out.println("File Run Location" + JavaSamp.filelocation);
           proc = rt.exec(JavaSamp.filelocation);

        } catch (IOException e4) {
           e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e2) {

        }
     }
  });
```

My problem is, the above execution of the JavaSamp.filelocation, should have to done many times. First time only I load the exe. Next time I wont. I need to store the exe in a string to run for the successive times. 
Any suggestion pls

Comment: You know of the `new File("dir", "name")` constructor?

Comment: Also you can print out `file.getAbsoluteName()`

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused -- what is preventing you from storing it in a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want remember the used file just initialize the `filelocation` with null and test for it. BTW: Storing it as `File` makes more sense and your way of constructing the absolute path is a bit intricate - compared to just calling `getAbsolutePath()`

```
private static File filelocation = null;

private static void test() {
    load_exe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Check if file-name to execute has already been set
            if (filelocation != null) {
                try {
                    JFileChooser file_Choose = new JFileChooser();

                    file_Choose.showOpenDialog(frame);
                    JavaSamp.filelocation = file_Choose.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("FileLocation"
                            + JavaSamp.filelocation.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (Exception expobj) {
                }
            }
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            try {
                System.out.println("File Run Location"
                        + JavaSamp.filelocation.getAbsolutePath());
                Process proc = rt.exec(JavaSamp.filelocation
                        .getAbsolutePath());

            } catch (IOException e4) {
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```